# SQL query for getting records whose specific instance is not present in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables. I want to get all students id from table A who never went to college.
So result should only return "2" here.

```
Table A
Student ID
1
2
3
```

```
Table B
1 - School
1 - College
2 - School
3 - School
3 - College
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find records on multiple fields not in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30296988/find-records-on-multiple-fields-not-in-another-table)

Answer (score 1):

one way is to use `not exists` which is the fastest if you are working with huge data:

```
select *
from TableA
where not exists ( select 1 from table2 
                   where table1.studentid = tableb.studentid 
                   and schoolcol = 'college'
                 )
```